# paypal android sdk bad currency error

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

On sandbox I am getting this error when I try to charge with card

11-02 11:19:48.577  24102-24840/com.***.*** E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failure with http statusCode:400,exception:Bad Request
11-02 11:19:48.585  24102-24840/com.***.*** E/paypal.sdk﹕ request failed with server response:{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].amount.currency","issue":"Value is not supported at this time"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"1b3357f0964d3"}
11-02 11:19:48.587  24102-24102/com.***.*** E/paypal.sdk﹕ pp_service_error_bad_currency

Answer (score 4):

I know  it's been awhile since you made this question, but as per the official documentation of PayPal's SDKs, the only currencies that PayPal supports for credit card payments are `USD`, `GBP`, `CAD`, `EUR`, and `JPY`.

See the reference links:

- [PayPal Currencies](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#currencies)
- [PayPal REST API Country and Currency Support](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#currencies)